# Unable to recalculate the total sum of a column on filtering in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sum, tablefilter

I am really struggling with some code. I am trying to get the total of a specific column in a table, my code is below.

It works in terms of providing me the total of the column - but when I filter the table, the total amount remains the same and doesn't change when filtered.

For example, when I load the page - the sum of the *transaction_amount* column amounts to 99 - but when I filter this to search for a different account in the filter, it still throws 99 as the sum. This is probably really simple, but I have been struggling for some time now. Hoping you can help?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table thead th').each(function(i) {
            calculateColumn(i);
        });
    });

    function calculateColumn(index) {
        var total = 0;
        $('table tr').each(function() {
            var value = parseInt($('td', this).eq(index).text());
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                total += value;
            }
        });
        $('table tfoot td').eq(index).text('Total: ' + total);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container box">
   <h3 align="center">How to Get SUM with Datatable Server-side-processing in PHP</h3>
   <br />

 <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <th> Date</th>
            <th>Account</th>
            <th> Transaction Name</th>
            <th> Type</th>
            <th>Method</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th> More</th>
           </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {        
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
            <tr class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="row-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"> 
                <td style="width: 11%" class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["submitted_date"]; ?></td>
                <td style="width: 11%"class="table table-bordered table-striped" > <?php echo $row["posting_account_number"]; ?></td>
                <td style="width: 45%"class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["transaction_name"]; ?></td>
                <td style="width: 22%"class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["method"]; ?></td>
                <td width="11%"class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["type"]; ?></td>
                <td class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["transaction_amount"]; ?></td>
                <td class="table table-bordered table-striped" align = "" colspan="2">
                  <a <a href="" type="link" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"> Details</a> </a>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
```

Comment: `but when i filter the table` can you provide an example of what you mean by this because I'm not seeing it?

Comment: Hi - for example, the datatable has a filter. So, if i change the textbox filter in the table to read as a different account number - so the table only displays records that have that account number in the row, the table filters correctly, but the sum in the bottom row doesn't change at all

Comment: I will need to see the rest of your code. It appears that `calculateColumn()` is what would need debugging, if given everything else is working properly.

Comment: I logged in. Delete your last comment.

Comment: However, now what. What am I supposed to be looking at?

Comment: Done - thank you. Couple of problems on the page - the table seems to sum every column, i only want it to sum the amount column. If you then filter the table to DOLTEST2, i want the sum to change so it only filters for that account but it doesnt if you know what i mean

Comment: I must be missing something. Im at a page titled "MyHub Web Portal"?

Comment: if you logged in, the full link is http://hub.nathanduncalf.com/go/fin_acc_entries.php

Comment: It's a bit tricky. Something must be breaking before this line `$('table tfoot td').eq(index).text('Total: ' + total);` gets a chance to execute, in some instances. Its value remains as a carry-over, meaning not a new calculation. ... Not the value, but the DOM isn't being updated; carry-over in that sense.

Comment: Ahh I see. You will need an *onchange* event or something to that effect to trigger your `calculateColumn()`. You have it for document load. But other than that, you are not triggering it when your filter text is changed.

Comment: Can you help me to add? really not sure - not too familiar with any of this haha

Comment: If you could update your post showing the code for your filter text input, and any event handlers associated with it. In the meantime i dont need to be logged in anymore. Needless to say, change your password.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of errors in HTML code in your code ... I wonder how it's running. `</head>` is written twice. `<a>` is added inside another `<a>`. `<tr>` is not closed. at the end. And other you have not closed the loop. Maybe that's why you could have been facing these issues. Rest, We need to check the filter code to tell in detail.

I have rectified your issues below.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table thead th').each(function(i) {
            calculateColumn(i);
        });
    });

    function calculateColumn(index) {
        var total = 0;
        $('table tr').each(function() {
            var value = parseInt($('td', this).eq(index).text());
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                total += value;
            }
        });
        $('table tfoot td').eq(index).text('Total: ' + total);
    }
</script>

<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Account</th>
          <th>Transaction Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Method</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>More</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
           if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
           {        
               while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
               {
                  ?>
                   <tr class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="row-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
                       <td style="width: 11%" class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["submitted_date"]; ?></td>
                       <td style="width: 11%"class="table table-bordered table-striped" > <?php echo $row["posting_account_number"]; ?></td>
                       <td style="width: 45%"class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["transaction_name"]; ?></td>
                       <td style="width: 22%"class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["method"]; ?></td>
                       <td width="11%"class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["type"]; ?></td>
                       <td class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["transaction_amount"]; ?></td>
                       <!-- action -->
                       <td class="table table-bordered table-striped" align = "" colspan="2">
                          <a href="" type="link" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"> Details</a>
                       </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
               }
        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
       <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Total:</td>
          <td></td>
       </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

> Updated Answer as per your requirement:

**Give a class to the amount  and in the js function, add the data of that class only.**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table thead th').each(function(i) {
            calculateColumn('.cal_amt');
        });
    });

    function calculateColumn(index) {
        var total = 0;
        $(index).each(function() {
            var value = parseInt($(this).text());
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                total += value;
                console.log(total);
            }
        });
        $('.show_amt').text('Total: ' + total);
    }
</script>

<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Account</th>
          <th>Transaction Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Method</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>More</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
           if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
           {        
               while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
               {
                  ?>
                   <tr class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="row-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
                       <td style="width: 11%" class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["submitted_date"]; ?></td>
                       <td style="width: 11%"class="table table-bordered table-striped" > <?php echo $row["posting_account_number"]; ?></td>
                       <td style="width: 45%"class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["transaction_name"]; ?></td>
                       <td style="width: 22%"class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["method"]; ?></td>
                       <td width="11%"class="table table-bordered table-striped cal_amt"><?php echo $row["type"]; ?></td>
                       <td class="table table-bordered table-striped"><?php echo $row["transaction_amount"]; ?></td>
                       <!-- action -->
                       <td class="table table-bordered table-striped" align = "" colspan="2">
                          <a href="" type="link" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"> Details</a>
                       </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
               }
        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
       <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="show_amt">Total:</td>
          <td></td>
       </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: I've sorted the filter issue. But, with the script below:


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table thead th').each(function(i) {
            calculateColumn(i);
        });
    });

    function calculateColumn(index) {
        var total = 0;
        $('table tr').each(function() {
            var value = parseInt($('td', this).eq(index).text());
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                total += value;
            }
        });
        $('table tfoot td').eq(index).text('Total: ' + total);
    }

it shows the sum of all columns, i just need the amount

Comment: Then give a class to the amount `<td>` and in the js function, add the data of that class only.